# XSLT replacing html in a node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I dont know how to translate the *guiLabel* to *strong* in the html output 
I'm trying to get the following html

output:

```
<p>lorem 1</p>
<p>lorem ipsum <strong>dolore</strong> amet</p>
<p>lorem 3</p>
```

from the following xml:

```
<para>1</para>
<para>lorem ipsum <guiLabel>dolore</guiLabel> amet</para>
<para>3</para>
```

my xsl file:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=". instance of element(para)">
            <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a `xsl:for-each` you should use a templated approach, with `xsl:apply-templates` and then a separate template match for the elements you wish to change.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="guiLabel">
    <strong>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </strong>
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: My answer does not contain a `div` element.... If you have just inserted my answer inside your current XSLT, then that would create a problem. It would probably help if you amended your question to show a complete sample of XML and XSLT, rather than just a fragment. Thank you!

Comment: thank you it works know i understand the usage of template